# can subsequent sleep() be skipped if the thread actually slept too long?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, jvm

Let's assume that I have a following loop in a Thread (Let's call it **Thread-A**).

```
while (threadCondition) {
  System.out.println(new Date());
  Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

and assume that other **Thread-B** will cause that the application is hanging up of the time >=2sec (because of some other Thread (Let's call it **Thread-B**, because of not enough CPU resources, low available memory, etc.)

Is it possible that when the **Thread-A** will come into action after those mentioned >=2 sec then the `System.out.println(new Date())` will be executed twice one after another ('instantly', without the sleep), and will print the equal date (with the same number of millis) twice?

Comment: No, the thread will always try to sleep for 1 sec after executing `System.out.println(new Date());`.

Comment: I don't understand -1 and closing votes. This is a specific question how JVM treats sleeps, when application is hanging.

Comment: I believe your question is misleading; I suggest rephrasing the question to be more general one. Using dates is really not important here. This question seems to be entirely about sleep duration.

Comment: Thx for the answer. I took this example from the real application which has this strange bug that when application hangs because of huge data the following loop produces equal date more than once. The example with dates is not so bad in my opinion because it shows where is the problem between current timestamp and sleep.

Comment: "instantly" - nothing is instantaneous on a computer.

Comment: @Dariusz but if you have an idea how I could refolmulate the question please edit it.

Comment: NTP can make time go backwards, just enough to see the same second twice, more than one second apart.

Comment: @ŁukaszRzeszotarski I kind of already have... :)

Comment: sleep always starts fresh no matter how long previous delays have been.  I suggest you also look at System.nanoTime() as it is more accurate and monotonically increasing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JVM does not guarantee the precision of time slept. It may wake after 996ms, 1003ms, or 2000ms - all are valid times

> However, these sleep times are not guaranteed to be precise, because
>   they are limited by the facilities provided by the underlying OS.
>   Also, the sleep period can be terminated by interrupts, as we'll see
>   in a later section. In any case, you cannot assume that invoking sleep
>   will suspend the thread for precisely the time period specified --
>   [source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html)

No track is kept of the amount of time the thread really slept.

When another `sleep()` is encountered, the thread will wait another (and again, more or less) 1000ms before waking.

Since the sleep time is not precise, it is possible that at time 10.000 your app printed the date once, and at 10.981 it printed the same date again, evn though almost once second has passed.

Also: remember, that the sleep() method may be interrupted. If the exception handling code is in this loop, the sleep may get interrupted, exception swallowed and two dates printed.

Answer (score 2):

Two calls to `new Date()` can give the same time if

- if is in the same milli-second
- if they are within the resolution of the clock. e.g. on Windows XP it is ~16 ms.
- if time is changed by NTP or similar. e.g. time can go backwards and repeat.
- if you use have byte code instrumentation to override the time. e.g. because you want a test driven clock.
- if two thread start 2 seconds apart but finish at the same time, they can print the same time.
- if thread B starts first and thread A starts after, thread B can print a time after thread A.  Just because it starts earlier doesn't mean it will finish first.
- new Date() will print the same date if they occur in the same second by default.

Answer (score 1):

No, Thread.sleep(...) delays execution from when it is called for the specified amount of time. There's no internal counter keeping track of "current time" which can become out of sync due to the thread being pushed to the background temporarily, which seems to be what you're thinking.

Comment: I see. I asked the question, because I have a strane minor bug in my application that two equal dates were produced. But if it is like you wrote it has to be different reason for that. However the problem occurs only when there is a lot of data and application is a bit hanging.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it is possible.

When application is hanging up because of any of the reasons you mentioned, it resumes executing from the line of code it stopped.

The fact that the code cause a hang that now may be redundant is irrelevant. You don't really expect the JVM to analyze your code...

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `System.nanoTime()` ( ie the high-resolution performance counter in the PC) in place of `date()`. And if you put the sleep in an if and write the condition correctly it won't sleep the thread.